# How to Filter the Results of a Query Using Data From a Related Table?

Tags: laravel

Imagine the scenario in a MongoDB structure:

```
"jobs" 1 -> * "tasks"
```

Where each task has a "version" column to be filtered by the "job" version.

So: job v1.2.3 has tasks 1.1.1 + 1.2.1 + 1.2.2 + 1.2.3

I'd like to create a query where I select the tasks filtering only the ones "=" the job version and use some pagination mechanism
(hope it makes sense hehe)

Here's what I was trying:

```php
$data = $this->model
    ->join('jobs', 'tasks.job_id', '=', 'jobs._id')
    ->where('jobs.version', 'tasks.version')
    ->offset($request->get('startRow'))
    ->limit(100)
    ->get();
```

But I'm getting empty results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this with [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).  Just keep in mind, this results in adding a sub-query to your statement, and some DB engines don't handle those very efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @claymore, I ended up making some extra stuff cause it's Mongo, but the whereHas clarified few things.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the **Laravel's Paginator**.

If you are working on an index method:

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){
    $data = DB::table('tasks')
         ->where('jobs.version', 'tasks.version')
         ->join('jobs', 'tasks.job_id', '=', 'jobs._id')
         ->paginate(20);

    return view('tasks.index',compact('data'))
         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 10);
}
```

**View:**

To show the paginator

```
{!! $data->links() !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: Hey @davide-casiraghi thanks for check, but I'm using mongoDB, so in this case is correct the "_id", sorry for not mention that

Comment: So in this case I've re-edit my answer. Did you consider Laravel's paginator? I guess it makes your life easier.